# How to use bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have used Bootstrap but the tooltip is not working

```
<a href="#" data-original-tittle="test" 
            data-placement="right"
            rel="tooltip"
            target=" _blank"> hover me 
</a>
```

Or do I need to use jQuery?

Comment: have you included js and css also..??

Comment: Why is there spaces everywhere?

Comment: i take this example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q9qfv/)

Comment: don't understand why this question is closed as "undefined"

Comment: I see that "title" is misspelled in "data-original-tittle".  Maybe that was your problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to add tooltip like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

or you can directly select as

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

or try with it

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"
data-original-title="Tooltip on right">hover me</a>
```

and your script like

```
$(function() {
    $('a').tooltip({placement: 'right'});
});
```

MY ULTIMATE FIDDLE finally [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/343/)

Comment: am using based on id as $('#ur').tooltip();

Comment: For your anchor tag you didnt put the id right..??

Comment: And also check that the relevant css and js also uploaded correctly

Comment: check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9qfv/)

Comment: now work but still tool tip is shown left side of screen and without any background color, only text is present

Comment: my code:  <a href="www.example.com" data-placement="right" rel="tooltip" target="_blank" title="www.example.com">hover</a>     but still tool tip on left side

Answer (score 0):

use `jqueryselectors` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: still can't get tool tip