# How to add Bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a tooltip on my code:

```
<a class="fa fa-facebook-square"
      href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{url absolute="true"}}" 
      onclick="window.open(this.href, 'facebook-share','width=580,height=296');return false;">
<span class="hidden">Facebook</span> </a>
```

Comment: Already asked... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461317/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461317/how-to-use-bootstrap-tooltip)

Comment: my code is little bit different

Comment: Maybe different, maybe not. You *must* try something first and ask later. Asking for code is off-topic and only brings downvotes. Consult the [help] for any doubts and for tips on how to improve your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work. Please let me know if it does not.

```
<a class="fa fa-facebook-square"
      href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{url absolute="true"}}" 
      onclick="window.open(this.href, 'facebook-share','width=580,height=296');return false;
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-placement="right"
      title="This is a tooltip!"">
<span class="hidden">Facebook</span> </a>
```

Comment: @MdNurullahHussain Thank you! Please let me know if you need any more help! You can find my email here: http://nahtnam.com