# Tooltip not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have input group in my form:

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon" data_toggle="tooltip" data_placement="left" data_content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." id="Contact">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeNo, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeNo, new {@class="form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeNo)
        </div>
    </div>
```

and tooltip called by this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Contact').tooltip();
});
```

Jquery and bootstrap included. No warning and errors in browser console.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think data attributes like data_toggle, data_placement should be data-toggle and etc.. - insted of _

Comment: Have a look at this

[How to use bootstrap tooltip? [closed]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461317/how-to-use-bootstrap-tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tooltip` function displays whatever you have added into the `title` attribute of your `div`.

So you should add the tooltip text to your `div`:

```
<div title="..." class="input-group-addon" data_toggle="tooltip" data_placement="left" data_content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." id="Contact">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeNo, new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
```

Another possibility would be to set the `content` property of the tooltip when creating it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Contact').tooltip({ content: "..." });
});
```

Comment: Thanks It's showing now but now I must find out why it's showing on the top although data_placement is set to left.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue to me. Have you the jQuery UI css loaded?

Comment: Try setting the position parameter: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using `data_content` here. However, bootstrap require `title` attribute for the tooltip, so add it to your `div`:

```
<div class="input-group-addon" data_toggle="tooltip" data_placement="left" title="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data_content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." id="Contact">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeNo, new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
```